# Powershell DSC manifest for subfolders

Tags: powershell, powershell-dsc

I am trying to create a Powershell module with class based DSC resource organized in sub folders. Something like this:

```
-MyModuleDsc
 \-DSCResources
   \-DSC_ManageVm
     |- DSC_ManageVM.psm1
|- MyModuleDsc.psd1
```

So the `DSC_ManageVM.psm1` has actual implementation of:

```
 [DscResource()] 
 class ManageVm {
   Get()
   Set()
   Test()
 }
```

So in main `MyModuleDsc.psd1` I defined:

```
@{

    RootModule = ''   
    ...
    ...
    NestedModules = @(
        '.\DSCResources\DSC_ManageVm\DSC_ManageVM.psm1'
    )
    ...
    ...
    DscResourcesToExport = @( ???? )
```

but how I should define `DscResourcesToExport` property

If I define it as `DscResourcesToExport = @('ManageVm')` then I receive an error while trying to `Invoke-DscResource` with message that:

```
Invoke-DscResource: Resource ManageVm was not found as one of the builtin resources. Please add -ModuleName parameter to include external resources.
```

So how I should define the `DscResourcesToExport` ? The idea is to keep adding new `DscResource()` classes each in it own subfolder